# Output and format array contents to HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datepicker, html-table

I am using Multiple Dates Picker v1.6.1. I basically want to grab the values in the array [picked] and produce a table with the values from the array onclick.

When you hover on picked in dubug mode in Firebug:

```
var min_date = this.multiDatesPicker.dates.picked[0],
```

It seems to store the dates like this (I think this is an array?):

```
[ Date { Thur May 09 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) }, 
  Date { Fri May 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) } ]
```

My question is how can i display the contents of just the Day Month Date and Year in the following format "Day Date Month Year" outputting into a table similar to this:

```
Dates Available     |   Price   |   Availability
Thur 09 May 2013        £1500        Available
```

Here is what i have tried so far to output the array:

```
$(function() {
      var html = '<table><tr>';
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) { // For each entry
            if (i == 3) { // Start of next row
                  html += '</tr><tr>'; // Add row separator
            }
            // Add date in cell
            html += '<td>data[i].id'></td>';
      }
      html += '</tr></table>'; // Finish up
      $('body').append(html); // And add to document
});
```